# Why does this ProcessWindowFunction always compute every incoming element and not all elements of one window?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-flink, flink-streaming, jmeter-5.0, flink-cep

I am working to set up a **Apache Flink Streaming Job** which computes very simple IoT data. 
It consumes (Source) from a RabbitMQ therefor uses RMQSource. This works fine and also the parsing of this data works fine.

However, for this parsed datastream - which is of type Triplet 'String, Double, Long' (SensorID, value of 'PM2,5', timestamp) - the applied function afterwards seems to be odd.
Firstly I want to key the Stream on the sensorIDs.
Secondly, I want to create a window containing all the elements keyed based on the ids every 10 or 15 seconds.
Thirdly, a very basic ProcessWindowFunction should be performed on this Window, which simply counts the elements in that window. => Basically, like the example from the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#processwindowfunction).
Finally, the output of the ProcessWindowFunction should be printed to Std.Out.

You can see the relevant parts of the below.
I use JMeter with MQTT and KafkaMeter plugin for sending test data, with which I send around 50 request at once and then see what happens.

When I send in 10 requests, results look like this:

```
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
nope :(
```

Which implies for my logic, that the ProcessWindowFunction gets computed for every value and not once for one window.

My questions now are:

1. Is there something I am missing? Why doesn't it just compute the function once and outputs me the number of elements in a window? (I already tried dozens of different versions, read through all relevant StackOverflow posts, followed tons of different tutorials, etc. Nothing worked).
2. Does the printing to the std.out have something to do with it (Also tried to write it in a file => same behaviour)?
3. I also tried using this
   `.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))` 
   with 
   `final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
       env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);` enabled -> in hope that it would work, but it didn't.

Help is very much appreciated.

```
extractedDataStream
                .keyBy(t -> t.getValue0()) // keyed by sensor IDs
                //.timeWindow(Time.seconds(10))
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .process(new DetectTooHighAirPollution())
                .print();

        // execute program
        env.execute("MQTT Detection StreamingJob");

    }

    public static class DetectTooHighAirPollution
            extends ProcessWindowFunction<Triplet<String, Double, Long>, String, String, TimeWindow> {


        @Override
        public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<Triplet<String, Double, Long>> input, Collector<String> out) throws IOException {

            long count = 0;

            for (Triplet<String, Double, Long> i : input) {
                count++;
            }

            if (count > 1) {
                out.collect("yap :D!: " + count);
            } else {
                out.collect("nope :(");
            }

             }
        }
    }
}
```

For sake of completness, the rest of the code, which does what it should do:

PS: I am sending MQTT messages with payload as JSON object, which I parse "by hand" at the moment.

PPS: Configuration Details have been deleted.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingProcessingTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.RMQSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.common.RMQConnectionConfig;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.javatuples.Triplet;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StreamingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);
        //env.setParallelism(1);

        // Set up a configuration for the RabbitMQ Source
        final RMQConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new RMQConnectionConfig.Builder()
                .setHost("")
                .setPort()
                .setUserName("")
                .setPassword("")
                .setVirtualHost("")
                .build();
        // Initiating a Data Stream from RabbitMQ
        final DataStream<String> RMQstream = env
                .addSource(new RMQSource<String>(
                        connectionConfig,            // config for the RabbitMQ connection
                        "",                 // name of the RabbitMQ queue to consume
                        false,                        // use correlation ids; can be false if only at-least-once is required
                        new SimpleStringSchema()))   // deserialization schema to turn messages into Java objects
                .setParallelism(1);              // parallel Source

        //Extraction of values of the Data Stream


        final DataStream<Triplet<String, Double, Long>> extractedDataStream = RMQstream.map(
                new RichMapFunction<String, Triplet<String, Double, Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Triplet<String, Double, Long> map(String s) throws Exception {
                        // Extract the payload of the message
                        String[] input = s.split(",");

                        // Extract the sensor ID
                        String sensorID = input[1];
                        String unformattedID = sensorID.split(":")[1];
                        String id = unformattedID.replaceAll(" ", "");

                        // Extract longitude
                        String sensorLONG = input[2];
                        String unformattedLONGTD = sensorLONG.split(":")[1];
                        String longtd = unformattedLONGTD.replaceAll(" ", "");

                        // Extract latitude
                        String sensorLAT = input[3];
                        String unformattedLATD = sensorLAT.split(":")[1];
                        String latd = unformattedLATD.replaceAll(" ", "");

                        // Extract the particulate matter
                        String sensorPM2 = input[6];
                        String unformattedPM2 = sensorPM2.split(":")[1];
                        String pm2String = unformattedPM2.replaceAll("[ }]+", "");

                        double pm2 = Double.valueOf(pm2String).doubleValue();

                        long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();


                        Triplet<String, Double, Long> sensorData = Triplet.with(id, pm2, ts);
                        return sensorData;
                    }

                }
        );
```

Thanks again, hope someone experienced this before, or can just point out the (maybe obvious) mistake I am making.

## UPDATE 21.11.2019

I was able to find a solution to my problem. I misunderstood & misinterpreted the concept of 'keyed Streams'. For my use case to get a single value result out of a Window when applying a ProcessWindowFunction, I did not need 'keyedStreams' at all. Rather I had to use the following code:

'.keyby' really constructs a single window for every sensorID in my case. So when 100 sensors (100 different ids) send requests in a very short time span (milli seconds) I get 100 windows and 100 ProcessWindowFunction results.

That's not what I want for my case, so I had to use the '.WindowAll' operation to get a single window with all elements of the stream. Afterwards I had to apply 'ProcessAllWindowFunction' instead of a 'ProcessWindowFunction' et voila:
It worked !:D

```
...
extractedDataStream
                //.filter(t -> t.getValue1() > 30) //This is just a use-case specific => 71/100 sensor requests have a higher value than 30.
                .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(15)))
                .process(new DetectTooHighAirPollution())
                .print();
...
public static class DetectTooHighAirPollution
            extends ProcessAllWindowFunction<Triplet<String, Double, Long>, String, TimeWindow> {

        @Override
        public void process(Context context, Iterable<Triplet<String, Double, Long>> input, Collector<String> out) throws IOException {

            long count = 0;

            for (Triplet<String, Double, Long> i : input) {
                count++;
            }

            if (count >= 10) {
                out.collect(count + " Sensors, report a too high concentration of PM2!");
            } else {
                out.collect("Upps something went wrong :/");
            }
        }
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: Keep in mind that the window is making a separate count for each key. Is it possible that there is only message per sensor during the 10 second window?

Comment: @DavidAnderson thank you for your comment, so pointed me in the right direction! I updated my Post with the solution :).